# Controlo de menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, symfony-2

Eu tenho um menu num bundle e tenho quero acrescentar a esse menu uma parte que está noutro menu, mas quero que esses menus apareçam ambos em todas as páginas.

O menu principal é este:

```
{# src/RoqSys/BaseBundle/Resources/views/Default/base.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 column">
        {% block menu %}
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            Início
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo">Configuração</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('gestaoutilizadores') }}">Utilizadores</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('gestaoparque') }}">Postos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionThree">Encomendas</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('registonova') }}">Registo de nova</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('encomendasabertas') }}">Encomendas em produção</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionFour">Produção</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul> 
                                <li><a href="{{ path('parqueinstalado') }}">Postos</a></li>
                                <li>Workflow
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="{{ path('registolote') }}">Nova Ordem de Fabrico</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ path('resistooperacao') }}">Registo de Operação</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 column">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

E a outra parte do menu é:

```
{# src/RoqSys/ManutencoaBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'RoqSysBaseBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}

{% block menu %}
{{ parent() }}
<div class="panel-group" id="accordiontwo">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Vista</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordiontwo" href="#accordionSix">Intervenção</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_intervencao') }}">Lista das Intervenções</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_intervencao_new') }}">Nova Intervenção</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordiontwo" href="#accordionSeven">Previsões</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_prevista') }}">Lista das Previsões</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_prevista_new') }}">Nova Previsão</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordiontwo" href="#accordionEight">Avarias</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="accordionEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_avaria') }}">Lista das Avarias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_avaria_new') }}">Avaria</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Consulta</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 column">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Só que a segunda parte do menu só parece quando ponho barra de endereço manutenção, e eu queria que aparece-se sempre.

Eu quero que fique assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mas aparece assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se o arquivo `index.html.twig` estende o arquivo `base.html.twig`, basta colocar o bloco que você quer no bloco pai.

`base.html.twig`:

```
{# src/RoqSys/BaseBundle/Resources/views/Default/base.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 column">
        {% block menu %}
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            Início
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo">Configuração</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('gestaoutilizadores') }}">Utilizadores</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('gestaoparque') }}">Postos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionThree">Encomendas</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('registonova') }}">Registo de nova</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('encomendasabertas') }}">Encomendas em produção</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionFour">Produção</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul> 
                                <li><a href="{{ path('parqueinstalado') }}">Postos</a></li>
                                <li>Workflow
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="{{ path('registolote') }}">Nova Ordem de Fabrico</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="{{ path('resistooperacao') }}">Registo de Operação</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordiontwo">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Vista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordiontwo" href="#accordionSix">Intervenção</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_intervencao') }}">Lista das Intervenções</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_intervencao_new') }}">Nova Intervenção</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordiontwo" href="#accordionSeven">Previsões</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_prevista') }}">Lista das Previsões</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_prevista_new') }}">Nova Previsão</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordiontwo" href="#accordionEight">Avarias</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="accordionEight" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_avaria') }}">Lista das Avarias</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ path('manutencao_avaria_new') }}">Avaria</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Consulta</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 column">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

`index.html.twig`:

```
{# src/RoqSys/ManutencoaBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig #}
{% extends 'RoqSysBaseBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: pois mas isso já tem na quinta linha do base.html já esta o block menu.

Comment: Então: é só copiar o conteúdo do bloco menu de index.html.twig para o bloco menu do base.html.twig. Assim o menu que aparecia em apenas algumas páginas agora aparece em todas.

Comment: o problema é que no BaseBunble esse menu está a ser chamado em vários ficheiros e ManutencaoBundle esse menu também está a ser chamado em vários ficheiros, mas nos ficheiros que está dentro no ManutencaoBundle e no BaseBundle só o menu que está dentro do BaseBundle é que está a ser chamado.

Comment: Isso não é necessário. Deixe o bloco menu apenas no base.html.twig e apague o bloco dos outros arquivos. Assim você não estende o bloco e ele fica como está definido no arquivo inicial.

Comment: o que eu tenho nos ficheiros de ManutencaoBundle já está a chamar o menu base {% extends 'RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}

{% block content -%} chama no base na penúltima linha

Comment: Como está sua hierarquia de arquivos do twig? E qual problema você está tendo atualmente?

Comment: Basicamente quero que os dois menus fiquem juntos num só e que apareçam em todas os meus ficheiros dos dois bundles.

Comment: Rodrigo Rogotti veja as imagens acima.

Comment: Fiz uma correção no código, pois o bloco `content` aparecia duas vezes e estava dentro do bloco `menu`. A solução que eu propus resolve seu problema: basta deixar o bloco `menu` apenas em `base.html.twig` (na verdade você nem precisa declarar o bloco `menu`, se ele não será estendido nos outros arquivos) e não declará-lo nos outros arquivos.